# Office Web Apps Server unavailable externally

Tags: office-web-apps, office

We configured an office web apps farm and it works perfectly internally.  But it prompts external users to log into the office web apps servers.  The screenshot below is from the ULS log when I try to log in externally.  I see differences obviously, IsAuthenticated=False UserIdentityName = , and missing access token.  I just dont know what this means.  I've looked online but there is not much concerning these keywords and SharePoint.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I assume you have already published your office web apps url externally? Did you set it up to use SSL?

Answer (score 0):

We finally figured out the problem.  The ASA rules were directing outside connections to the wrong internal IP.  Once we corrected the routes on the ASA, everything ran smoothly.  I guess the prompt appeared because that incorrect IP address from the ASA was not bound to the office web apps farm so the farm was asking who the unknown request was coming from.